# Meteor: How do I adjust iron router return data based on search query?

Tags: meteor

I have an app where users can take notes.

In the html page I iterate over each note like so:

```
<div id="notes-container" class="notes">
  {{each notes}}
    {{> note}} 
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

and in my router file I return the data like so:

```
@route: 'notes'.
  path: '/notes/:_id',
  data: ->
      notes = Notes.find
          threadId: @params._id
          trash:
            $exists: false
        ,
          sort: 
            date: -1
```

All is typical meteor stuff so far. But I am confused now about how to adjust the data that is iterated on in the html page.

Each notes has a array field for tags like tags: ['apple' ,'red', 'green']

What if the user wants to return all notes with the tag 'red'. So there is a input box on the site the user enters a tag and presses enter.

How can I adjust the data that is sent to the page so queries mongodb to return all notes with tag red? I know how to write the query I am not sure how to set this up though in meteor.

One way I tried to do it is called the same route with query paramters like: '/notes/326363235474?tags=apple'

And in iron router I can look for query parameters and return the right set of documents but then when I call the original route again to clear the search, it does not load all of the original documents again.

Any suggestion on how I can set this up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the data function simply needs to return the data you want available within the template context, if I'll define this function to a certain route:

```
 data: ->
        return Drawing.findOne
            _id: window._drawing_id
```

I will have that data in my "this" object when proccessing that template.